# How can I determine the video playback capabilities of an iOS device?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer, photosframework

I use an `AVAssetExportSession` in my iOS app to save edited videos as an `mp4` file to disk. This video file can then be shared or added to the user's photo library.

The `Photos` framework doesn't allow to save assets to the photo library that the device isn't capable of playing back. For example, an iPad mini 2 does not support playback of video resolutions that are greater than 1080p, so such videos cannot be added on that device.

I want to make sure that the exported video can always be added to the photo library and automatically export at a lower resolution if needed.

How can I determine this limit? Can the device's video playback capabilities be queried during runtime, or are they documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Apple engineer has confirmed that the playback capabilities cannot be determined during runtime.

Video playback capabilities are documented on Apple's [Tech Specs pages](https://support.apple.com/en_US/specs/iphone). iPhone models can be compared [here](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/).